# showing a set of solutions is convex.

Tags: linear-programming

I have already shown that the set of all feasible solutions of the LP $ \min \{ cx : Ax = b , x \geq 0 \}$ is convex. Now, Im asked to show that the set of all optimal solutions to this LP is convex as well. But, how can I express the set all of optimal solutions? how is it defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ouch, this is a long time ago for me. Let me try.

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be two optimal (and feasible) solutions with objective $z$. We have to show that $x=\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2$ is feasible and has objective $z$ for $0\le\lambda \le 1$. The feasibility was already established in your earlier result, so we only have to prove these points in between have objective $z$.

$$\begin{align} &c^T\left[\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2\right]\\
                &=\lambda c^Tx_1 + (1-\lambda) c^Tx_2\\
                &=\lambda z + (1-\lambda) z\\
                &=z\end{align}$$

Comment: why show the set  =1+(1−)? you didnt explain that part of the logic

Comment: That, by definition, makes it convex.